# What does retain persistent mapping variable value mean in informatica when importing a mapping(XML file) in the repository

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to import a mapping from a folder to my DEV environment. I already have the same named mapping in DEV environment so I did replace in conflicts window that popped up. After that it is asking me to check a box that says retain persistent mapping variable value. Does it mean:

1: It will retain persistent variable values from the import file XML that I'm trying to import in DEV.or
2: It will retain persistent variable values from the earlier same named mapping that I have already in the DEV env repository.

which is it? Please help

I tried the above that I am mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check it Infa will retain persistent variable values in **target** repository/folder.

For example, if you are migrating a mapping which has a sequence generator with initial value as 5000 in production and 10 in dev, while migrating if you check the option `retain persistent mapping variable`, after migration from Prod to Dev, value of seq gen initial value will be 10. Because it retained the value in Dev.

This is mostly used in case of lower environment to higher environment migration. In prod, if value is higher, its always a good idea to retain that higher and correct value and we check this option.

In your scenario i would say not to retain dev values because it will not be consistent with prod.